# Use C function in MASM programm

Tags: c, include, call, masm, extern

I have C function and I want to use that in my MASM program.

C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int go() {
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 10;
}
```

I used this command in gcc: `gcc -c go_func.c`
After I've got `go_func.obj`

But, I can't compile/translate my MASM program, since I don't have the address of go function there. Maybe I need to create dll (static or dynamic)?

prog.asm:

```
.386p
.model flat, stdcall
; include c:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include c:\masm32\include\user32.inc
include c:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
include c:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc

includelib c:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
includelib c:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib c:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

extern go@0:NEAR

_data segment dword public use32 'data'

_data ends

_text segment dword public use32 'code'

START:
    call go

_text ends

end START
```

I can't call that function, because I don't have a pointer to function?

Comment: You don't need it. The linker takes care of it. It's exactly the same when you have two different C files and you call a function in file2.c from file1.c.

Comment: Ok, but why I get this message?
`prog.asm(24) : error A2006: undefined symbol : go`

Comment: That's crucial information that belongs into the question. Please [edit] your question and put all relevant information _there_.

Comment: Not sure at all by try `extern go:NEAR`

Answer (score 0):

You want [a `PROTO` declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/proto?view=vs-2019) for your function that tells MASM to use the C calling convention.  In this case, that would be `C`, but not `NEAR` (which is an obsolete 16-bit calling convention from the ’80s).

Comment: I added `go PROTO NEAR C`, It's working, when I try to use `printf`, I get error from linker.

`addf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___acrt_iob_func referenced in function _printf`
`addf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vfprintf referenced in function __vfprintf_l
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals`

Comment: You need to link in the C runtime library, which your C function calls. (You also should **not** need `NEAR`.)

Comment: Which C runtime library you need will depend on whether you compiled your C object file for `x86_64-pc-mingw32` or `x86_64-pc-msvc`. I’d recommend the latter here, which allows you to link to MSVCRT, or use the MSVC linker. It’s more compatible with MS.

Comment: I’ve had success with Clang, if GCC won’t play nice with MSVC. Or the GCC linker might accept your MASM object file.